# x64 Linux reverse-engineering - understanding asm code and inject eax

Tags: linux, x86-64

In a rootme exercise, i'm trying to bypass the control impleted to protect a "read" function. You'll find enclosed the code i'm refering to. As you may understand, i can inject data (with limitations) in rax (with the limitation that ax be under 100h due to the previous instruction:

```
cmp ax, 100h
```

I know I can change eax value before entering that part of the programe (part of the programe before the asm instructions enclosed). However, I have the feeling that the following instruction prevent from reading the ah part of the eax register.

```
movzx eax, word ptr [rax]
```

Would you have any idea if it would be possible to write into the upper bits of `rax` so that it be taken into account by the read function?

Thanks a lot! Sorry if all is not very clear, I can try to re-explain if needed.

[image: disassembled piece of code]

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean the upper bits of `rax` rather than `ah`? There seems to be a vulnerability (presumably created by compiling and not handling the 32-bit to 64-bit conversion correctly).

If the address stored at `[rbp+username_buffer_input]` is beyond the 4 GiB space, then the upper 32-bits will contain a non-zero value in register `rax`. The following code can then lead to a very large nbytes value and potential for a buffer overflow.

```
mov rax, [rbp+username_buffer_input]    ; upper 32-bits of rax may not be zero
movzx eax, word ptr [rax]               ; doesn't clear out upper 32-bits when reading from an address > 4 GiB
movzx eax, ax                           ; doesn't clear out upper 32-bits
...
mov rdx, rax                            ; uh-oh - nbytes can have a non-zero value in the upper 32-bits of rax carried over from above
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer! You're right, I meant the upper bits of `rax` so that the upper bits of `rdx` don't get zero-ed. I do not really understand your statement on line 2: "doesn't clear out upper 32-bits when reading from an address > 4 GiB".  When debugging with `gdb`, I can see that upper bits of `rax` are cleared when performing the first movzx while `rax` valued previously `0x7fffffffe410` so that it is a bit confusing...

Comment: Let's say `rax` was `0x7fffffffe410` and the 16-bit value at that address was `0x1234`. After the `movzx eax, word ptr [rax]` instruction,  `eax` would be set to `0x00001234` but `rax` would be `0x00007fff00001234`

Comment: I understand your idea   I tried earlier to monitor this behaviour through `gdb`, but it ended with a different result:   I set a breakpoint on the `mov rax, [rbp+username_buffer_input]` line and performed:    `i r rax`: `rax            0x7fffffffe410   140737488348176`  `x/s $rax`: `0x7fffffffe410: "\003"`    Ok, this is fine until here, however, after a step in `si` i performed a `i r eax rax` resulting in `eax  0x3  3` `rax  0x3  3`.  So the question would be: would you know a compilation option or system option which could forced the behaviour you were describing earlier?

Comment: any more ideas?